# NGINX log filter $upstream_response_time JSON ELK "-" parsefailure

Tags: json, nginx, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have my NGINX logs formated as JSON:

```
log_format le_json '{ "@timestamp": "$time_iso8601", '
                   '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
                   '"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
                   '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
                   '"status": $status, '
                   '"request": "$request", '
                   '"request_method": "$request_method", '
                   '"response_time": $upstream_response_time, '
                   '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
                   '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" }';
```

My log gets picked up by filebeat and sent to Logstash that have the following config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}
filter {
    geoip {
      database => "C:/GeoLiteCity.dat" 
      source => "[remote_addr]"
          }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    template => "C:/ELK/logstash-2.2.2/templates/elasticsearch-template.json"
    template_overwrite => true
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

The problem i'm having is $upstream_response_time. When there is no response time  NGINX puts an '-' on this post. As you can see i don't put "" around $upstream_response_time because i want it as a number so i can perform calculations with this in Kibana and display. When '-' is sent i get a jsonparsefailure in Logstash because it is not a number.

I would like to set all the '-' to 0. What would be the best way to do this?
I've had no success with trying to filter it in nginx-config. I think it needs to be done prior to getting shipped to Logstash because that's where the parsefailure occurs.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a workaround hack you could put a zero after it. So it either become `0.1230` or `-0`, both are perfectly valid numbers :)

Comment: Or use `map` directive

Comment: You don't need slashes in regexp, and you even don't need regexp at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
map $upstream_response_time $temprt {
  default $upstream_response_time;
  ""      0;
}
```

`$upstream_response_time` either a number or unset. Nginx logs unset variables as dash (`-`), but `map` treats them as empty strings.

Comment: Thanks!
This worked:


`map $upstream_response_time $temprt {
  default $upstream_response_time;
  ""     0;
 }`

Seems like it was empty and somewhere behind the scenes it's set to "-" if thats the case.

Comment: Thanks, fixed answer

Comment: @JesperPersson nginx replaces unset variables with dashes in log module https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_log_module.c#L957-L960

Answer (score 0):

A fleshed out example from @AlexeyTen using null instead of 0 to differentiate from real values since I wasn't 100% sure how to use mapped variables:

```
map $upstream_response_time $temprt {
  default $upstream_response_time;
  ""      null;
}

log_format le_json '{ "@timestamp": "$time_iso8601", '
               '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr", '
               '"remote_user": "$remote_user", '
               '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent", '
               '"status": $status, '
               '"request": "$request", '
               '"request_method": "$request_method", '
               '"response_time": $temprt, '
               '"http_referrer": "$http_referer", '
               '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" }';
```